# Count occurrence of values in a serialized attribute(array) in Active Admin dashboard (Rails, Active admin 1.0, Postgresql database, postgres_ext gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activeadmin

I'd like to have a basic table summing up the number of occurence of values inside arrays.

My app is a Daily Deal app built to learn more Ruby on Rails.

I have a model Deals, which has one attribute called Deal_goal. It's a multiple select which is serialized in an array.

Here is the deal_goal taken from schema.db:

```
t.string   "deal_goal",:array => true
```

[image]

So a deal A can have deal= goal =[traffic, qualification] and another deal can have as deal_goal=[branding, traffic, acquisition]

What I'd like to build is a table in my dashboard which would take each type of goal (each value in the array) and count the number of deals whose deal_goal's array would contain this type of goal and count them.

My objective is to have this table:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I think I would need to group each deal_goal array for each type of value and then count the number of times where this goals appears in the arrays. I'm quite new to RoR and can't manage to do it.

Here is my code so far:

```
column do
    panel "top of Goals" do
          table_for Deal.limit(10) do
            column ("Goal"),  :deal_goal ????
            # add 2 columns:
            'nb of deals with this goal'
            'Share of deals with this goal'
          end
        end
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any clean way to get the results you're after through ActiveRecord but it is pretty easy in SQL.

All you're really trying to do is open up the `deal_goal` arrays and build a histogram based on the opened arrays. You can express that directly in SQL this way:

```
with expanded_deals(id, goal) as (
    select id, unnest(deal_goal)
    from deals
)
select goal, count(*) n
from expanded_deals
group by goal
```

And if you want to include all four goals even if they don't appear in any of the `deal_goal`s then just toss in a LEFT JOIN to say so:

```
with
    all_goals(goal) as (
        values ('traffic'),
               ('acquisition'),
               ('branding'),
               ('qualification')
    ),
    expanded_deals(id, goal) as (
        select id, unnest(deal_goal)
        from deals
    )
select all_goals.goal goal,
       count(expanded_deals.id) n
from all_goals
left join expanded_deals using (goal)
group by all_goals.goal
```

**SQL Demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f0af/20

Throw one of those into a [`select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows) call and you'll get your data:

```
Deal.connection.select_rows(%q{ SQL goes here }).each do |row|
  goal = row.first
  n    = row.last.to_i
  #....
end
```

---

There's probably a lot going on here that you're not familiar with so I'll explain a little.

First of all, I'm using WITH and Common Table Expressions (CTE) to simplify the SELECTs. [WITH is a standard SQL feature](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) that allows you to produce SQL macros or inlined temporary tables of a sort. For the most part, you can take the CTE and drop it right in the query where its name is:

```
with some_cte(colname1, colname2, ...) as ( some_pile_of_complexity )
select * from some_cte
```

is like this:

```
select * from ( some_pile_of_complexity ) as some_cte(colname1, colname2, ...)
```

CTEs are the SQL way of refactoring an overly complex query/method into smaller and easier to understand pieces.

[`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is an array function which unpacks an array into individual rows. So if you say `unnest(ARRAY[1,2])`, you get two rows back: `1` and `2`.

[VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html) in PostgreSQL is used to, more or less, generate inlined constant tables. You can use VALUES anywhere you could use a normal table, it isn't just some syntax that you throw in an INSERT to tell the database what values to insert. That means that you can say things like this:

```
select * from (values (1), (2)) as dt
```

and get the rows `1` and `2` out. Throwing that VALUES into a CTE makes things nice and readable and makes it look like any old table in the final query.

Comment: thanks a lot. i think you're right to do it in sql commands , i tried to do it in pure ruby and it wasn't the way to go. it's a lot indeed going on in your advice and thanks for the detailed explanation. i'll try it on my app tonight and will let you know how it worked. thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: thanks. I do manage now to get all the data i need inside an array of array but i can't use them/put them inside standard active admin's columns. i don't know if you're familiar with active admin but i've opted to put this issue inside a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730588/error-undefined-method-to-key-for-xxx-array-when-trying-to-use-array-data-o

Comment: would you have any idea on how to use this arrray inside active admin's table_for?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about ActiveAdmin as I don't use it. I'd be pretty surprised if it had so much attitude that it couldn't display a simple table of raw data; however, there is a sad tendency in the Rails world to substitute opinion and attitude for plain good sense.