# Iterating an array of array to streamline the code (Ruby, Rails, active admin 1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have an array of array called 'data' which is:
[image] (built it to adjust to use [sb's advice on Active Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730588/error-undefined-method-to-key-for-xxx-array-when-trying-to-use-array-data-o/20732791?noredirect=1#comment31064708_20732791))

I need to use its data to create a array of hash with this structure:

```
data_prepared_for_table = [{goal: data[0][0], number: data[0][1]},
                    {goal: data[1][0], number: data[1][1]},
                    {goal: data[2][0], number: data[2][1]},
                    {goal: data[3][0], number: data[3][1]},
                    {goal: data[4][0], number: data[4][1]},
                    {goal: data[5][0], number: data[5][1]}
                   ]
```

in data_prepared_for_table, Goal has to display the first part of the array 'date': acquisition, branding, qualification.

Number has to display the related quantities in the array 'data' such as 3 , 2, 1.

I'd like to do 2 things:

- streamline/improve the code by using a lop each or for, that would enable me to generate data_prepared_for_table
  something like:

  ```
   data_prepared_for_table = [(0..5).each do |i|
                      {goal: data[i][0], number: data[i][1]},                        
                     ]
  ```

  But it doesn't work and creates an error. How should I do it?
- another thing is that in the example I give it goes up to data [5][0] but I want to be able to not specify the end (5 here) in case the array get longer and goes up to data [6] or even more [7] , and so on... 
  I actually don't know in advance how long it will get!

How can I do it without specifying the last value of `i`? Maybe in the iteration, specify that `i` has to increment until `data[i][0].exists?`?

Comment: can you show an expected output what does goal and data refer to?

Comment: @bjhaid just added some explanation. It's very basic: i have an array with goal_type and for each goal_type a number. I need to use the information that is inside the array called 'data' to create another array called data_prepared_for_table. i manage to do it but as i said i'd like to DRY/streamline/reduce the code thanks to a loop/iteration if possible. I also need to provide for the case where i don't know what will be the number of values in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to throw a little [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) in the mix to map your array to the format your want:

```
array_of_hashes = array_of_arrays.map { |a| { :goal => a.first, :number => a.last.to_i } }
```

You may or may not want the `to_i` call but it probably makes sense given the history of your task.

You could also combine this with where the original query:

```
array_of_hashes = Deal.connection.select_rows(...).map do |row|
  { :goal => row.first, :number => row.last.to_i }
end
```

to avoid the intermediate array (assuming of course that you don't need the array-of-arrays for anything).

---

The problem with this:

```
data_prepared_for_table = [(0..5).each do |i|
                {goal: data[i][0], number: data[i][2]},                        
               ]
```

is that you have a stray comma inside the `each` block, you're looking at `data[i][2]` instead of `data[i][1]`, and most importantly, [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) returns its receiver so you're really writing this:

```
data_prepared_for_table = [ (0..5) ]
```

with a bunch of extra noise.

Comment: indeed i don't need intermdiary array. just used directly .map! thanks